# Deploying to Vercel shows build error when using React hooks like (useEffect, useState)

Tags: next.js, vercel

That is the error from Vercel.

The way I import those hooks in Next.js is like this

```
import { useState } from 'react';
```

I tried doing it like this

```
import React from 'react';
```

but still, it shows the error. I really don't know why. Please help!

[image]

[image: Here's my code I removed the React class and just use it plainly, but still get the same error when building it]

Comment: According to the error, you're calling a hook outside a Component or Custom Hook. You can read a bit about the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

Comment: I added a screenshot of my code. I don't think the hooks are called outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by ensuring my React functional component's naming starts with an uppercase.

So from

```
export default function login()
```

to

```
export default function Login()
```